# TypeScript Error 2304: Cannot find name 'div' - CRA TypeScript Template

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I'm having an issue in VSCode using the out-of-the-box `create-react-app my-app --template typescript` project not recognizing any element. I constantly get the error **cannot find name xxx** with 'xxx' being whatever the HTML element I'm using in the JSX.

What's interesting is that the project will run initially with zero edits. As soon as I actually go into `App.tsx` and change anything or create a very basic new component it breaks.

Here's a very basic component I attempted to make following [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/tutorials/React.md) tutorial from the TypeScript Handbook Github.

```js
// src/components/Hello.tsx
import React from 'react';

export const Hello = () => {
  return <h1>Hello < /h1>;
};
```

Once more this project is created directly from the recommended TypeScript template using `create-react-app my-app --template typescript`. No files were edited.

It came with their own `tsconfig.json` ready to go.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Of course they had their own `package.json` as well.

```json
{
  "name": "ts-trial",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.52",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "typescript": "4.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Once more no files were edited - I ran the command, `cd`ed into my new project, created `Hello.tsx` and as soon as I put an element in the `return` statement it said **Cannot find name 'h1'. ts(2304)**.

Then I went to `App.tsx` and as soon as I opened it the same error was showing all over too.

I filed an issue on GitHub as I don't see how I could be getting this error honestly. I've searched for hours and most of the solutions I found weren't relevant for my particular issue. Most solutions were forgetting to change file extensions from `.js` or `.ts` to `.tsx` for React. Or they had to specify `"@types/node": "^12.0.0"` in `package.json`, or `target`, `lib`, `module` or `include` in `tsconfig.json`, all of which I have.

**Environment Info:**

**System**:

- OS: macOS 10.15.6
- CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7660U CPU @ 2.50GHz

**Binaries**:

- Node: 14.6.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
- Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
- npm: 6.14.7 - /usr/local/bin/npm

**Browser**:

- Firefox Developer Edition 82.0b7 (64-bit)

**npmPackages**:

- react: ^16.13.1 => 16.13.1
- react-dom: ^16.13.1 => 16.13.1
- react-scripts: 3.4.3 => 3.4.3

**npmGlobalPackages**:

- create-react-app: 3.4.1

**Code Editor**: VSCode

Comment: Could you make a Github repo with the whole project (except node_modules, to save space) committed to it? It would be a lot easier to help debug this as a folder, where we could see your organization, rather than copy-pasted in here.

Answer (score 36):

The file extension has to be `.tsx` in order for this to work.

Answer (score 5):

I have renamed my file .tsx, but the problem persisted. it was with how i exported my component.
I tried this and it worked.

My component was

```
export default InsertDocuments = () =>
```

I changed it to

```
const InsertDocuments = () =>
//etc
export default InsertDocuments
```

or

```
export const InsertDocuments = () =>
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting the VS Code typescript version to the version inside your workspace should fix it.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64976666/6753500

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same problem. I discovered that I had 100 extensions installed in VS Code and one of them was causing the problem. I dont know which one it was but, after I disabled all the extensions, it started working.

Comment: An extension was also the issue for me, I tried installing a lot of snippet ones and others I wasn't using. Don't know exactly which one it was.

Comment: VS-code extension "React-Native Custom Snippets" was bringing the issue. after disabling it and restarting the VS-code, it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was HCL AppScan Security extension which was causing trouble. Disabled it and then it worked like charm.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Extra space in close tag `< /h1>` -> `</h1>`

Comment: The extra space is a result of Prettier trying to format with an error present. Unfortunately, if I correct the spacing and save it will go straight back to that due to the underlying error of **cannot find name xxx**.

The `App.tsx` file is even worse after saving due to the same errors.

Comment: This seems to have received a bunch of downvotes, but I was able to fix the problem with the reported error in VS Code by adjusting spacing in my code base, so it's plausible to me that this was a genuine solution to the issue, if unexplained.