# Problem with Visual Studio Code using "react-jsx" as jsx value with create-react-app

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsx, create-react-app, tsconfig

I'm struggling with following "error" in VSCode :

```
Argument for '--jsx' option must be: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react'
```

Hence, react-scripts (create-react-app) automatically sets the `jsx` key to `react-jsx` value, when `react` value seems to work.

Actually, the code works perfectly and displays the page I want, but the IDE is underlining kinda everything as errors, saying :

```
Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided.
```

Here is my tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

, and my package.json (default one provided by create-react-app + packages updated) :

```
{
  "name": "front-office",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.9",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm using the latest version of Typescript, and I updated all my packages with `ncu`, closed/opened VSCode (works sometimes with tsconfig !) and nothing seems to resolve that.

I'm pretty sure it's a VSCode problem, but I'm running out of ideas about how to resolve that.

Any of you guys got ideas ?

Edit:

If you followed the above steps and VSCode still shows the "*-jsx*" error, make sure you have disabled the 'TypeScript God' extension (and any other TS extension until the issue no longer appears).

Answer (score 142, accepted):

This is because VSCode's Typescript version is not using the newest babel features that create-react-app uses by default.

You can [change VS Code to use the workspace's version of Typescript instead](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-the-workspace-version-of-typescript), which will fix this issue.

> Open a TypeScript or JavaScript file and click on the TypeScript version number in the Status Bar. A message box will appear asking you which version of TypeScript VS Code should use

Select "Use Workspace Version" to use the newer Create React App typescript version.

Comment: Seems it was a mix between that and the extension I was using (TypeScript God) that may not be up to date. Anyway, it solved my problem, thanks !

Comment: How can I change the workspace version if the project is split into multiple sub-folders? VSCode doesn't seem to pick up `node_modules` in sub directories or at least I don't see other versions available

Comment: @Narigo I installed the version I wanted globally (`npm i -g typescript@4.1.2`) then added this line to vscode settings json file `"typescript.tsdk": "/home/yourusername/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib"`
Substitute `/home/yourusername/.nvm/versions/node/v10.15.1/lib/node_modules` for your global npm node_modules folder path (find out with `npm root -g`)

Comment: My VSCode is using an upper version than one from my project, and It still has problems.

Comment: For me it was changing my `settings.json` to use the local typescript version: `"typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"`

Answer (score 29):

In PhpStorm (and the same is probably true for WebStorm) I got it to not complain about "react-jsx" as the value by ticking "Always download the most recent version of schemas" in Remote JSON Schemas.

[image: The option that needs to be ticked]

Comment: I believe that the question was regarding vscode ....

Comment: True, since I myself found this issue searching for PhpStorm, I thought maybe this could help others as well. Also this could help in being a clue regarding vscode that the issue will have something to do with JSON schemas probably being old.

Comment: This did help me as I'm using WebStorm. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by others, this is an open issue with create-react-app (CRA) script. However, none of the above mentioned solution worked for me. The only solution that works for me is adding the below config in `.env` file (in project root).

```
DISABLE_NEW_JSX_TRANSFORM=true
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this can be obvious for the majority but I always forget to use `.tsx` file extension in React and then I'm hitting my head trying to understand why the JSX code is throwing an error.

So, make sure you are using **`.tsx`** extension and NOT **`.ts`** !

Answer (score 2):

For the ones using VS 2019 I had to install typescript 4.1 for visual studio from here:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.TypeScript-41

Then it worked fine by using the new jsx setting in the compilerOptions etc.

Answer (score 1):

I did managed to solve this issue by uninstalling the,

```
ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets extension
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VS Code and marksfrancis' answer didn't work for you. Maybe you should check your extensions for TypeScript, in my case the extension 'TypeScript God' was the cause I was still having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Installing [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next) and reselecting TS version in VSC (when .tsx is opened, click on TS version (right bottom), then "Select TypeScript version" -> "Use VS Code's Version") also works.

(src: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-typescript-nightly-builds )

Answer (score 0):

for any one it may help, I just restarted VS code.
Credit: https://exerror.com/cannot-use-jsx-unless-the-jsx-flag-is-provided/

Answer (score -1):

If you tried updating the typescript version by selecting "Use Workspace Version" in your vscode editor and it still shows the error, try updating the value of the field `"jsx"` in your .tsconfig file to `"preserve"`.

- This will enable you to write JSX the old way.

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
}
```

- If you use the value `"react-jsx"` value, you will have to write react in the new React 17 Transform:

```
import { jsx as _jsx } from "react/jsx-runtime";
export const helloWorld = () => _jsx("h1", { children: "Hello world" }, void 0);
```

.tsconfig file reference (per typescript docs): [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#jsx)

new JSX Transform (per react docs): [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html)