# Parsing error: Argument for '--jsx' option must be: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, visual-studio-code

I am learning firebase cloud functions and in my **index.ts** folder I get the error message highlighted under **import**

I have no idea what it means and how to solve it the worst part is that the same exact code worked in the firebase tutorial video on youtube

what is wrong with this code?

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

// Start writing Firebase Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", { structuredData: true });
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

Here is my tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: Can you post your tsconfig file?

Comment: I added it, I think mine is the same to yours

Comment: is your `index.ts` in the `src` directory?

Comment: yes it's in the `src` directory

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

add "jsx": "react" in compilerOptions

Answer (score 2):

If your setup is a monorepo with multiple packages, it's possible that the problem is due to multiple different versions of typescript. I had 2 different major versions across several packages. When I unified them to a single one, the error was gone.

Or may be typescript version of your editor vs the project [as depicted here](https://www.supercodebros.dev/typescript-react-jsx-flag/)

Comment: This was the issue for me in a Turbo monorepo with multiple Typescript apps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have an error in your `tsconfig` file. Specifically, you probably have an option definite called `jsx`. I would guess that you in fact don't need JSX parsing for your Firebase cloud functions, but I could be wrong.

Here's an example of my `tsconfig` for Firebase cloud, which works (you may need slightly different options, of course):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

It is also possible that your `src` directory is not leading to the location of your Typescript source files.

Finally, it's possible that VSCode is making assumptions about your Typescript setup that aren't correct -- this could be because you don't have a `tsconfig` file or because VSCode is using a different version of Typescript than your project. See possible solutions for that here: [Problem with Visual Studio Code using "react-jsx" as jsx value with create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64974648/problem-with-visual-studio-code-using-react-jsx-as-jsx-value-with-create-react)

Some other resources referencing this error:

- [Build: Cannot use JSX unless the '--jsx' flag is provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169911/build-cannot-use-jsx-unless-the-jsx-flag-is-provided)
- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15814
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript

Comment: I think the problem is my eslint settings, however I never really changed them as well. I just don't get it how come I get so many ESLINT errors on the folders that firebase generated automatically?

Comment: Your `eslint` settings could very well be VSCode global defaults and not specific to the firebase project (unless you have a linter config file in your firebase directory)

Comment: Did you look at all the solutions listed in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64974648/problem-with-visual-studio-code-using-react-jsx-as-jsx-value-with-create-react

Answer (score 0):

Just add the  `"jsx": "preserve"` in the compilerOptions object in your jsconfig.json file